# Constructor for importing file

Tags: java, constructor

If I wanted to build a constructor for a class to import a file, which I have passed in a String nameOfFile, how can I initialize the object's state, then open the document file, and process each line of the document? References and clear explanation would be appreciated. I'm just beginning to learn java.

To clear up my question, how can you build an object for a document file you have imported? What I'm doing right now is that I have wrote a class but i'm struggling with building an object for a SPECIFIC file. What I have thus far is

```
public class theImport 
{

theImport(String nameOfFile)
{
(Here is where I want to achieve all the listing I have above.)
}
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "initialize the object's state"?
By calling the constructor, you're initializing the object.

Comment: You can make your question better by adding some sample data in the file, and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise, it just looks like you have copy-pasted (homework) question here, asking for a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would do this in a two-step process.

Step one: The actual constructor.

```
private String nOF;
public ClassName(String nameOfFile) {
    nOF = nameOfFile;
}
```

Step two: Evaluation of the file. Since this can fail for a variety of reasons (for example the file not existing, it shouldn't go to the constructor (you can't catch these errors from a return type you aren't having in the constructor)

```
public boolean Evaluate() {
    //Evaluate your file and return false if it fails for whatever reason.
}
```

My Java isn't the best at the moment, but this should tip you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Propably you mean something like this:

```
    public class theImport 
    {

          theImport(String nameOfFile)
          {
            try { 
                    FileReader input = new FileReader(nameOfFile);
                    BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
                    String line;
                    line = bufRead.readLine();
                    //this will loop thought the lines of the file
                    while (line != null){
                          line = bufRead.readLine();
                          //do whatever you want with the line
                    }
                    bufRead.close();
            }           
            catch (Exception e){
                   e.printStackTrace();

            }
         }
   }
```